# How to read only A-Z and a-z from a PHP file

Tags: php

I want to read only the alphabetic content from a file and neglect the rest of the special characters. How to achieve this?

I intend to use 
`$content = file_get_contents($argv[1]);`

How can I make sure `$contents` does not contain any special character.

Comment: And what is the actual question? Obviously `file_get_contents()` reads the file as it is. So you have to filter the contents of `$content` afterwards. Did you try that?

Comment: @arkascha sorry for the confusion. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to extract only A-Z and a-z, use this:

## test.txt

```
abcdzjsi3424mmdnsn12312312
```

## test.php

```
$content = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$only_az = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s]/', '', $content);
echo $only_az; //Output: abcdzjsimmdnsn
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you it works but it eats the space. Example: `abc def` , output: `abcdef`. I want the spaces to be intact

Answer (score 0):

`$content = preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]/', $content );`

Comment: try with ```preg_match_all```

Comment: it prints some integer instead of the text. :/

Comment: so the echo of LHS prints some integer value.

Comment: ok remove the caret (^) ```$content = preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]/i', $content );```